# lxc container is not starting

Tags: containers, lxc

I am using LXC container and want to add some capabilties to it
so

```
 set lxc.cap.keep = sys_ptrace in var/lib/lxc/container_name/config
```

but after doing this container is not starting and giving error

**container requests lxc.cap.drop and lxc.cap.keep: either use lxc.cap.drop or lxc.cap.keep, not both**

Comment: I want to add ptrace capability in the container, so that from the container, ptrace system call can be called.